# Spring receiving empty body

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring for my backend. I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@CrossOrigin
public void test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getParameterMap().size());
    System.out.println(new JSONObject(request.getParameterMap()));
}
```

When I send JSON data using Postman, I get a map of all the parameters I've sent.
But when I'm making the same call from my website, I get an empty map with size 0. I do not get any error or exception on both front and back sides.

What could be the reason?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `getParameterMap()` is really empty in your case, because parameters are not passed as query, but as a body (content) of HTTP request when it is sent from your web-site.

It can also be affected by the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers of the HTTP request.

According to official documentation [ServletRequest.getParameterMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) returns:

> For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.

Usually "posted form data" implies: HTTP header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and URL encoded name-value pairs of parameters in the content of HTTP request.

If your web-site sends `application/json`, any other content type, or does not define content type at all, it might not be properly mapped into the request parameters by servlet container. In this case you should look into the body of HTTP request ([ServletRequest.getReader()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader())) to get the payload, or let Spring MVC do that (e.g. `@RequestBody` annotation).